# How to change choice field value in SharePoint programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, .net

```
SPFieldChoice chFldCategory = (SPFieldChoice)lst.Fields["Category"];
                          chFldCategory.EditFormat = SPChoiceFormatType.Dropdown;
                          chFldCategory.Choices.Add("Category 12");
                          chFldCategory.Update();
```

In this code I am setting column value to `Category 12` of column `Category`.

Can anyone help me change these values with another.

For ex now I have value `Category 12`, how can I replace with some other value lets say `Category 4`.

Answer (score 2):

If got your requirement correctly, you need to replace an existing value like `"Category 12"` by another value like  `"Category 4"`.

So remove `"Category 12"` at first

```
chFldCategory.Choices.Remove("Category 12");
```

Now add `"Category 4"` in the `Choices`

```
chFldCategory.AddChoice("Category 4");
```

Check `SPFieldChoice` methods in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice_methods.aspx).